# adonis message modular message exception

Tags: node.js, adonis.js

i have handle exception in adonis but the message is not can not change base condition
what i expected is i can change message error in any controller

```
'use strict'

const { LogicalException } = require('@adonisjs/generic-exceptions')

class InvalidAccessException extends LogicalException {
  /**
   * Handle this exception by itself
   */
  handle (error, { response }) {
    return response.status(403).json({
      error: error,
    });
  }
}

module.exports = InvalidAccessException
```

and in my controller if there is error i just trow error

```
throw new InvalidAccessException("user already register");
```

but the error message is always empty

Comment: Your question is quiet hard to understand (please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please improve your question

Comment: Did you try `error.message`? source : https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/errors/what-is-the-error-object/